# Jackson filter its response based on JSON field

Tags: json, jackson

I parse about ~300kb (it might grow) json file, so instead of using default Android's JSON parser I've used Jackson. However, I have to filter it's response based on value of field (from JSON's object). Example:

Json File:

```
     {"foobars":[{"foo":1,"bar":1},{"foo":2,"bar":2}]}
```

and the response will be an ArrayList (in my case) with these two objcets. However I'd like to get the objects only if "foo" < 2. How to do that?

Comment: Why you do not want to filter list after deserialization instead of changing input JSON?

Comment: I'll have to do that, I work with Android so I thought that it would be faster the way I've described.